# SQLAlchemy causing memory leaks

Tags: python, flask, memory-leaks, sqlalchemy

App startup memory

```
Partition of a set of 249162 objects. Total size = 28889880 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  77463  31  5917583  20   5917583  20 types.CodeType
     1  30042  12  3774404  13   9691987  34 function
     2  51799  21  3070789  11  12762776  44 tuple
     3  15106   6  2061017   7  14823793  51 dict of type
     4   5040   2  1928939   7  16752732  58 function, tuple
     5   6627   3  1459448   5  18212180  63 type
     6   5227   2  1346136   5  19558316  68 dict of module
     7  16466   7  1026538   4  20584854  71 dict (no owner)
     8    734   0   685897   2  21270751  74 dict of module, tuple
     9    420   0   626760   2  21897511  76 function, module
```

App memory after 100 subsequent calls (interacting with SQLAlchemy)

```
Partition of a set of 628910 objects. Total size = 107982928 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  23373   4 27673632  26  27673632  26 sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Column
     1 141175  22 20904408  19  48578040  45 dict of sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Column
     2  78401  12  5984371   6  54562411  51 types.CodeType
     3  34133   5  4239726   4  58802137  54 function
     4  64371  10  3661978   3  62464115  58 tuple
     5  20034   3  2971710   3  65435825  61 dict of sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table
     6  13356   2  2297232   2  67733057  63 sqlalchemy.sql.base.ColumnCollection
     7  15924   3  2133374   2  69866431  65 dict of type
     8   5095   1  1946855   2  71813286  67 function, tuple
     9   8714   1  1793696   2  73606982  68 type
```

Helper function that detects memory usage by rcs

```py
def heap_results():
    from guppy import hpy
    hp = hpy()
    h = hp.heap()
    return Response(response=str(h.bytype),
                    status=200,
                    mimetype='application/json')
```

The implementation of SQLAlchemy is fairly straightforward. Using the db.Model, we are creating a class for ORM, and breaking the tables into subfunctions of the ORM class.

We are `gc.collect()` just before returning the final response to the user. We are also using `db.session.flush()`, `db.session.expunge_all()`, and `db.session.close()`.

We have tried to remove the `db.session.*` commands, as well as the `gc.collect()`. Nothing changes.

Here is a timeseries graph of our app's memory usage, the application being restarted is where you see the memory cap reset back to a stable state:
[image]

Code to simulate an HAProxy.

```py
def reconnect():
    hostnames = [Settings.SECRETS.get('PATRONI_HOST_C', ''), Settings.SECRETS.get('PATRONI_HOST_E', '')]

    try:
        master_node = HAProxy(hostnames=hostnames)

    except (ValueError, TypeError, BaseException) as e:
        # send an alert here though, use the informant!
        raise e

    else:
        if master_node in ['None', None]:
            raise ValueError("Failed to determined which server is acting as the master node")

    my_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(Settings.SECRETS['PATRONI_USER'],
                                                                                 Settings.SECRETS['PATRONI_PASSWORD'],
                                                                                 master_node,
                                                                                 Settings.SECRETS['PATRONI_DB'])

    my_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
    'pool_recycle': 1800
    }

    new_db = SQLAlchemy(my_app)
    new_db_orm = DBORM(new_db)
    return new_db_orm
```

What the DBORM (modified to hide full functionality) looks like:

```py
class DBORM(object):
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.database = database
        self.owner_model = self.owner_model()

    def create_owner_model(self):
        db = self.database

        class OwnerModel(db.Model):
            __tablename__ = "owners"
            owner_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True,
                                      nullable=False, primary_key=True)
  
            client_owner = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False, nullable=False)
            admin_owner = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False, nullable=False)

            @staticmethod
            def owner_validation(owner_model, owner=None):
                if owner is not None:
                    owner_model = OwnerModel.get_owner_by_id(owner_id=owner_id,
                                                                  return_as_model=True)
                    if owner_model is not None:
                        client_owner = owner_model.client_owner
                        admin_owner = owner_model.admin_owner

                        if client_owner is None and admin_owner is None:
                            return False

                        elif client_owner.lower() == owner.lower():
                            return True

                        elif admin_owner.lower() == owner.lower():
                            return True

                        else:
                            return False

                    else:
                        return None

                else:
                    return None
```

Example of Using OwnerModel from API

```py
@api.route('/owners/{owner_id}')
def my_function(owner_id):
   try:
      dborm = reconnect()

   except (AttributeError, KeyError, ValueError, BaseException) as e:
      logger.error(f'Unable to get an owner model.')
      logger.info(f'Garbage collector, collected: {gc.collect()}')
      return Response(response=Exception.database_reconnect_failure(),
                      status=503,
                      mimetype='application/json')

   else:
      response = dborm.get_owner_by_id(owner_id=owner_id)

   logger.info(f'Garbage collector, collected: {gc.collect()}')
   return Response(response=json.dumps(response),
                   status=200,
                   mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: The memory usage only resets upon a full application restart. Since we are likely able to identify SQLAlchemy as the culprit, we just want to know if there is a way to shutdown the references of SQLAlchemy, or if there is something we are missing. As a highly scalable application, it does not bode well for our services if we cannot handle high IO.

Comment: Are you by any chance creating new `Table` and `Column` objects repeatedly? You really should provide a [mcve] for this one.

Comment: Okay, i updated the original message to include some code examples of how we are instantiating the Database ORM. Unfortunately, the connection is HA, so we need to reconnect each time we interact with it to ensure we are getting the master node (Write Priviledges).

Comment: @IljaEverilä See above^

Comment: `create_owner_model` does look like it keeps on creating new versions of the same model. Does that happen often? Depending on your setup those will not be GCd, because SQLAlchemy `MetaData` and declarative base both hold registries of created tables and models. That's because your application should create them only once, and if you need to change from one DB instance to another, just swap the `Engine`. Usually you don't need to do that either, and you create the engine just once per application life cycle.

Comment: We are getting about 2500 API calls every 3 hours. So everytime a new API call happens, this functionality is performed. Is there a way to resolve this, so that it does not keep recreating new versions of it?

Comment: Do you have an example of what swapping the `Engine` would look like? We have been struggling with this issue for a few months now and have gotten very little feedback. This would be huge for us. @IljaEverilä

Comment: I think using a suitable combination of pooling and a custom connection factory might be one approach where you wouldn't need to swap the world every time. Will have to look around a bit, if someone has come up with it already, and wrote about it in SO.

Comment: Btw. what package provides the `HAProxy(hostnames=hostnames)`, or is it your own helper? If the latter, what does it do exactly?

Comment: HAProxy is hitting the Patroni endpoint deployed onto our Postgres instances. It is determining which of our database instances in the acting `master` (rw priv) and returns that master host. It is a helper method we have defined locally.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared that. I'm sorry that I've not had the time to come up with an answer, it happens that we changed country recently, and that's been a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy `MetaData` holds references to `Table` objects and the Declarative base class also has an internal registry for lookups, for example for use as context in `relationship()` lazily evaluated arguments. When you repeatedly create new versions of model classes, which also creates the required metadata like `Table`, you likely consume more and more memory, if the references are kept around. The fact that `Column` objects dominate your memory usage supports this in my view.

You should aim to create your models and their metadata just once during your application's life cycle. You only need to be able to change the connection parameters dynamically. SQLAlchemy versions up to 1.3 provide the `creator` argument of `Engine` for exactly this, and version 1.4 introduced `DialectEvents.do_connect()` event hook [for even finer control](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#fully-replacing-the-dbapi-connect-function).

Using `creator`:

```
import psycopg2

db = SQLAlchemy()
dborm = DBORM(db)


def initialize(app):
    """
    Setup `db` configuration and initialize the application. Call this once and
    once only, before your application starts using the database.

    The `creator` creates a new connection every time the connection pool
    requires one, due to all connections being in use, or old ones having been
    recycled, etc.
    """
    # Placeholder that lets the Engine know which dialect it will be speaking
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql+psycopg2://"
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
        'pool_recycle': 1800,
        'creator': lambda: psycopg2.connect(
            dbname=Settings.SECRETS['PATRONI_DB'],
            user=Settings.SECRETS['PATRONI_USER'],
            password=Settings.SECRETS['PATRONI_PASSWORD'],
            host=HAProxy([
                Settings.SECRETS.get('PATRONI_HOST_C', ''),
                Settings.SECRETS.get('PATRONI_HOST_E', ''),
            ]))
    }

    db.init_app(app)


class OwnerModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "owners"
    ...
```

Note that you need to change `DBORM` to use the global `db` and model classes, and that your controllers do not call `reconnect()`—that does not exist—anymore, but just use `db`, `dborm`, and the classes directly as well.

Comment: This might fail "Unfortunately, the connection is HA, so we need to reconnect each time we interact with it to ensure we are getting the master node (Write Priviledges)" at the moment, and that sounds a bit like you should not be then pooling connections at all, or at least for a very short time. You might also then add an event handler that ensures that the connection checked out from the pool is able to write; something like the builtin pre ping feature. Necessary reading: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#more-on-invalidation